# Whitening Transformation of a Data Matrix in numpy does not replicate MATLAB results

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to do a Whitening transformation (or a sphering transformation) of a matrix in numpy. There are a number of ways to do this (for e.g., by calculating eigenvalues), but I'm looking for the solution to this particular approach I describe below. I am trying to raise a covariance matrix to a negative fractional power.

This is how one does it in MATLAB with an example matrix A:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12];
C = cov(A);
C^-0.5
```

As the answer, I get a matrix whose elements have real and imaginary parts.

When I try to do the same in Python as below, I get a matrix of nans:

```
from scipy.linalg import fractional_matrix_power
import numpy as np

A=np.asarray([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])
C=np.cov(np.transpose(A))
fractional_matrix_power(C, -0.5)
```

Am I missing something here?

I tried the solution [suggested in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364653) but I'm not sure if this is calculating what I want. The resulting matrices in MATLAB and Python are not the same (because the solution of this problem (C<sup>-0.5</sup>) is not unique?).

```
from scipy.linalg import logm, expm
E = -0.5*logm(C)
F = expm(E)
```

The equivalent MATLAB code is:

```
expm((-0.5)*logm(C))
```

Is there a way to check this? For example, is the square of C<sup>-0.5</sup> equivalent to the inverse of C, in which case their multiplication will result in Identity Matrix?

While trying to debug on Python, I ran into some other strange things too (not directly related to the problem above, but may hint at some problem I'm facing).

**Multiplication of a matrix and its inverse is not I**

```
D = fractional_matrix_power(C, 0.5)
E = np.linalg.inv(D)
np.dot(E,D)
```

The above operation does not return an Identity matrix. Should it not? It does in MATLAB. I also used scipy.linalg.inv instead of the numpy version, but didn't help.

Comment: For what it's worth, your Matlab whitening code also results in an array of nans in Octave.  Your matrix `C` is singular.  I suspect `fractional_matrix_power` requires a nonsingular matrix when the power is negative.

Comment: I tried with a non-sintular matrix A = np.asarray([[1,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]]) and python seems to produce some output (although not identical to MATLAB).

Could this be the reason? Any idea why MATLAB does not complain about this?

Comment: Also, with this new nonsingular matrix, I get completely different results in Python for these two operations: expm(-0.5*logm(C)) and fractional_matrix_power(C,-0.5). The results are identical in Matlab for both operations.

Comment: With the new `A`, are you still computing `C = np.cov(np.dot(A,np.transpose(A)))`?  If so, then that `C` is also singular.

Comment: If it is singular, shouldn't python complain when I try to calculate its inverse (scipy.linalg.inv(C))?

Are you saying that there's no way to solve this problem with numpy?

Comment: *"...shouldn't python complain..."*.  `inv()` might not detect that its argument is near-singular (it isn't *exactly* singular--arrays computed using floating point are rarely exactly singular).

Comment: By the way, are you sure of the formula `C = cov(A*A')`?  Shouldn't it be just `C = cov(A)`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. /=I mixed up the example from something else I was doing. Will edit the question.